# How do I install and enable wireless drivers on laptop with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

So I recently got this free laptop from a relative and it had Ubuntu on it, and I gave it to my brother since I don't need it. However, he ended up messing it up and I had to re install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14 on it. I managed to give it life again, but now the wireless doesn't work(not appearing is the right word I guess), I have tried searching for possible driver updates, but none appear( connected to an Ethernet of course..). I have tried some terminal commands, but didn't work because when I get to the modprobe part, it always says it's in use? Is there anyone that knows how to get it so that it starts detecting wireless networks again?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the internet was connected to the laptop during installation (PREFERABLY WITH AN ETHERNET CABLE)the wireless drivers would not have installed.

To correct that, when faced with laptops brought to me for help, the solution which always works for me is to connect an ethernet cable as you already have, and to perform an update in the following manner:

With the ethernet cable connected, open the graphical ubuntu Update Manager.  CLICK CHECK.  Then click install updates.  Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if there is a combination of buttons that activate Wi-Fi (like Fn+F8)? If not, you want to go in Settings -> Programs and updates -> Additional Drivers. I think is that, 'cause my Ubuntu is not English. Hope that I helped =)
(Sorry for bad English)